# Add icon to TListView

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to put an icon in `TListView` when certain rows show and I have the `TImageList` with the loaded image, but it does not connect. The code that I have is this

```
with sListView2 do
begin
  test := sListView2.Items.Add;
  test.Caption := sListbox2.Items[i];
  test.SubItems.Add(test');
  test.ImageIndex(ImageList1.AddIcon(1));
end;
```

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TImageList.ImageIndex` is an integer, and you need to properly set it, and to call `AddIcon` you need to provide it a `TIcon`.

If you already have it in the `TImageList`, just set the `TListView.ImageIndex` to the proper index of that image:

```
// Assign an image from the ImageList by index
test.ImageIndex := 1;  // The second image in the ImageList
```

Or, if you don't have an existing icon in the `TImageList` and need to add one, add it and store the return value from `AddIcon`:

```
// Create a new TIcon, load an icon from a disk file, and
// add it to the ImageList, and set the TListView.ImageIndex
// to the new icon's index.
Ico := TIcon.Create;
try
  Ico.LoadFromFile(SomeIconFileName);
  test.ImageIndex := ImageList1.Add(Ico);
finally
  Ico.Free;
end;
```

BTW, you can simplify your code slightly (be careful with `with`, though!):

```
with sListView2.Items.Add do
begin
  Caption := sListbox2.Items[i];
  SubItems.Add(test');
  ImageIndex := 1;
end;
```